# Why does nothing appear ? Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/pingu/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'pingu']);

Auth::routes();

Route::prefix('jobs')->group(function(){
    Route::get('create', function () {
        return "create";
    });


    Route::get('update', function () {
        return "update";
    });
});
```

TaskController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TaskController extends Controller

{    public function create(){
            return view ('create');
    }
}
```

create.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Dashboard') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="{{route('jobs.store')}}" method="POST">
                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I did exactly what to do in the turtorial but it dind't appear , please find fix that works. I use laravel  8 i tried to config :cache clear a nd then artisan serve again butdind't work .If you know a laravel enough ( 8 ) you should know that everything is done right .

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlY1D.png)

Comment: have run php artisan serve command ?

Comment: Yeah i did run php artisan serve.

Comment: it works fine as per screenshot

Comment: no it should show a submit button.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with your route.

```php
Route::prefix('jobs')->group(function(){
    Route::get('create', function () {
        return "create";
    });
```

That will return the word `create`. You most likely actually want:

```php
Route::prefix('jobs')->group(function() {
    Route::get('create', [App\Http\Controllers\TaskController::class, 'create']);
});
```

The above tells Laravel to use the `create` function on your `TaskController` which returns your `create` view.

You also don't need to include `Auth::routes()` more than once. Include it before your routes just once.

**Update**

For the `Did not work`; here is a working example in black and white for you.

https://phpsandbox.io/n/round-morning-pqpk-dm8j1

Comment: I tried the solution and this one dind not work.

Comment: That's not helpful. What did not work, what did you see or not see?

Comment: Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [jobs.store] not defined. (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/blog/resources/views/create.blade.php)

Comment: You've not defined a route for `jobs.store`. That is a separate issue from your question and the solution I have provided.

Comment: look at picture 1 or 2 i still doesen't works

Comment: It is working, you need to replace the content of the view file with **your** content.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `return "create";`, I think you meant to `return view('create')`. Please check and confirm.

Comment: Acctually it isn't return view because return view is given in the taskcontroller.