# Do you know why the button doesen't appears?

Tags: php, laravel

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/pingu/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'pingu']);

Auth::routes();

Route::prefix('jobs')->group(function(){
    Route::get('create', function () {
        return "create";
    });


    Route::get('update', function () {
        return "update";
    });
});
```

TaskController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TaskController extends Controller

{    public function create(){
            return view ('create');
    }
}
```

create.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Dashboard') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="{{route('jobs.store')}}" method="POST">
                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

I did exactly what to do in the turtorial but it dind't appear , please find fix that works. I use laravel  8 i tried to config :cache clear a nd then artisan serve again butdind't work .If you know a laravel enough ( 8 ) you should know that everything is done right .
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bm3u2.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does nothing appear ? Laravel 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67860828/why-does-nothing-appear-laravel-8)

Answer (score 2):

You are instructing Laravel to return the word 'create' via the closure on your routing in **web.php** here:

```
Route::get('create', function () {
    return "create";
});
```

It never gets to the **TaskController** because it just sees the closure and returns the single word.  You will need to give the routing instruction to go to the **TaskController** in order to get this to work.

See docs on routing [Laravel Routing Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing) to give you a head start.

It will tell you something similar to this (but please review the docs to ensure this will work for you):

```
Route::get('create', [App\Http\Controllers\TaskController::class, 'create']);
```

I don't know your folder structure, but I also suspect that when you get the routing correct, the `create()` method in that controller may have an issue with finding the file for the view here:

```
return view ('create');
```

Make sure you specify any folder if it is not in the `views` folder directly :)

Comment: Still only shows me create. Do you know a other fix.

Comment: If it worked, mark the answer as correct please !